# How to replace email domain misspellings

Tags: python

I manage a booking system where people enter their emails to book appointments. Unfortunately, many of the email addresses have typos, especially in the top-level domain. I'd like to implement a function to identify when the domain should be .com, which should be all cases where it starts with ".c".

I wrote the function and tested the individual lines, which seem to work. But when I run the function on a set of emails, it only returns the email with no ".c", meaning it only returns 'my_name_is@orange.org'. The ideal output would be:

```
['me.you@perp.com',
'appleorange@msn.edu.com',
'laughable@gmail.com',
'notfunny@pointdexter.com',
'very.latin...word@word.nutherwork.com',
'very.latin..word@word.nutherwork.com',
'my_name_is@orange.org']
```

Any help would be appreciated!

```
emails = ['me.you@perp.comp',
'appleorange@msn.edu.cot',
'laughable@gmail.copl',
'notfunny@pointdexter.com',
'very.latin...word@word.nutherwork.com',
'very.latin..word@word.nutherwork.cnm',
'my_name_is@orange.org']

def domain(emails):
    for email in emails:
        parse_mail = email.split('.')
        parse_mail = parse_mail[-1]
        if parse_mail[0] == "c":
            email = email.replace(parse_mail,"com")
        pass
    return email

print(domain(emails))
```

Comment: you only check if the extension starts with c to convert it to `.com`. there are plenty of country codes starting with c that you will convert to .com making the email wrong. eg: Switzerland is `.ch`

Comment: Your current function only returns 'my_name_is@orange.org' because it is the last email in the list and that is what your function is currently returning, the last email in emails. Also, setting email = email.replace(parse_mail,"com") won't change the email in the list, you need to update the list of emails, the simplest way would be just by indexing.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the email without "c" because that's the last one in the array.

Your routine "domain" only returns the last email in the array. If you put the org address higher up, it'll return an email with a "c".

Answer (score 0):

I expect what you're looking for is:

```
def domain(emails):
    for i in range(len(emails)):
        parse_mail = emails[i].split('.')
        
        if parse_mail[-1][0] == "c":
            parse_mail = emails[i].split('.')[:-1]
            parse_mail.append("com")
            correct = '.'.join(parse_mail)
            emails[i] = correct
        pass
    return emails
print(domain(emails))
```

But as Sembei Norimaki, mentioned - this will also auto-correct (erroneously) other extensions beginning with a 'c'.